# Hands-free/Driving Mode: How to change the reading voice's language (and voice: male/female etc...)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, hands-free, driving-mode

Is there a way to change the language and voice for reading out the information on hands-free mode. Even better, it would be nice if the language and voice for the alarm could be set on a per-alarm feature. Anyone knowing if and how this can be done, please don't hesitate to reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **settings** > **language and input** > **text to speech output**.

There you can select one of your installed voices.
You can install voices from the Play Store.
My personal best and free is IVONA (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ivona.tts&hl=de)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also, I would like to know what the difference is between the options `Samsung text-to-speech engine` and `Google Text-to-speech Engine`. How do these engines differ from each other? Thanks. The main difference I see is that different sets of languages are supported, but maybe there are also other differences.

Comment: The samsung one is made by samsung and the google one by google. Both are standard TTS engines. If my answer was helpful you can accept it by checking it.

Comment: I've tried activating hands-free mode and setting the language to Samsung text-to-speech engine Chinese, and set an alarm with a message in Chinese to go off, but when alarm went off the voice was in English and the message I wrote in Chinese as part of the alarm was not even read out at all. So this is not working for me on my Samsung Galaxy SIII. Do you know what the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Google TTS Chinese or IVONA TTS Chinese

Comment: I don't see an entry for Chinese under Google TTS (although several other languages are listed). The reason I am a bit hesitant about installing IVONA Text-to-Speech HQ from Google Play Store is when I try to install it it requires the "In-app purchases" permission, which makes me a bit uneasy. Why is it requesting this permission? Is it safe to install? Thanks.

Comment: I've installed IVONA, but I see a message on Google Play Store about rebooting the device or reloading the TTS engine before using IVONA. How do I reload the TTS engine without rebooting? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've installed IVONA Text to Speech, but when I click on Install voice data, it brings me to the URL [http:///mobile.ivona.com/?set_lang=en](http:///mobile.ivona.com/?set_lang=en) which displays various voices but none in Chinese. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: OK, on my Samsung Galaxy SIII, now I've tried the Samsung TTS Italian voice, but phone data and alarm data was still being read out in English. Then I've tried installing IVONA Italian beta TTF, but this time, neither the alarm nor incoming phone calls were being read out at all, despite hands-free mode being enabled. So, I couldn't get your solution to work.

Comment: OK, here is the thing. Suppose I set `Settings -> My device -> Language and input -> Text-to-speech options -> Preferred TTS engine -> Samsung text-to-speech engine -> Language -> Italian (Italy)`. If I also set `Settings -> My device -> Language and input -> Language` to `Italiano` then when the alarm rings the message is read in Italian, but if instead I leave `Settings -> My device -> Language and input -> Language` set to `English (United States)` then the TTF settings are ignored and the message is still read out in English.

Comment: As a bilingual person, I would have preferred if I could set the TTF language directly alongside the alarm message, perhaps with a default suggested based on a setting somewhere under Language and input. Regards.

Comment: There I can't help you... Sorry.